# Удалил Убунту, который стоит рядом с Виндой, теперь не могу выйти из GNU GRUB 2.06

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, grub, gnu

Попробовал почти все, ничего не работает. Могу зайти только в биос, команда exit приводит к ошибке и стопору всей системы, чейнлоудер тоже не хочет работать. Через меню выбора загрузки, например, выбирал загрузку с флешки, чтобы заного поставить убунту — перекидывает в grub.
Ноутбук Тошиба Сателлит.

( в Windows зайти не могу )

Comment: А цель какая? Оставить только винду?

Comment: Ну либо ты через `Gparted Live` удаляешь все линуксовые разделы, а потом через `ERD Commander` делаешь `fixboot/fixmbr`, либо ставишь Убубнту обратно как было.

Comment: `чтобы заного поставить убунту — перекидывает в grub` ты явно что-то недоговариваешь. Или что-то не туда жмёшь. Оригинальный iso бубна отлично ставится вне зависимости от того чё до этого было на диске.